# What is the AssertNoError keyword in TestComplete JScript scripts?

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

In the TestComplete JScript script below, what does the `AssertNoError` keyword mean and what does it do?

```jscript
if(AssertNoError("UtilsCommon.DoesWindowExist","Explorer",1,"CabinetWClass","Temp",-1,WINDOW_WAIT_TIME)){ 
  //Get Reference of Temp floder and List of Files Present in it
  oTempFldRef = AssertNoError("UtilsCommon.GetWindow",Sys.Process("Explorer"),"CabinetWClass","Temp",-1,10000,true);       
  strTempList =  oTempFldRef.FindChild(["WndClass","Caption"],["DirectUIHWND","Items View"],5);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I think you need to elaborate a little bit. The queston is very vague ..

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in TestComplete function named `AssertNoError`. It must be defined somewhere in your project. You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click the function name to jump to its implementation.